# Установить результат в QFuture

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

В плюсах очень хочется повторить https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.set_result

Одно из применений: протокол при получении данных смотрит список фюьчерсов и устанавливает результат на соответствующий ответу. Протокол работает конкурентно. Фьючер ставится в список перед записью задания в сокет. Дальше его ждем через await или ставим колбэк.

Но не найду как добавить туда результаты.

Пробовал через future.results()<<res,  но или заблокировался поток или чтото ещё.

Comment: а как он в питоне используется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил на словах, за компом буду - добавлю в коде.

Comment: гм... в доках про `set_result` написано «*This method should only be used by Executor implementations and unit tests.*», так что я не могу отделаться от мысли, что ты делаешь что-то грязное... скорей всего прямого аналога нет: похоже, в Qt QFuture — это непрозрачный объект, используемый только в рамках QtConcurrent и не подразумевается, что это абстракция общего назначения... а в stl есть пара `std::future`/`std::promice` и установка значения вынесена в последний...

Comment: Так я и делаю имплементацию экзекутора, с той лишь оговоркой что выполняю команды на удаленном сервере.

std::promice это для вызова в тредах, а интересно запускаться на mainloop чтоб ожидание не блокировало прочие сигналы. В QT6 добавили QPromice с нужном функционалом.

Comment: В Qt5 это невозможно (без создания отдельного потока для каждого future). Используйте либо `std::future<>`, либо Qt6: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpromise.html

Comment: @Chorkov QFutureInterface  похож на то что нужно

Comment: @eri, если всё в одном потоке, то может всё на обычных сигналах — слотах сделать? `QFutureInterface` — штука недокументированная... а `std::future` ни что не мешает и в одном потоке использовать (если не ждать), но интегрировать его с eventLoop'ом (Qt'шным или своим) нормально не получится...